# Easiest way to add a GUI to a Python code?

Tags: application-development, python, raspberrypi

I'm planning out a Raspberry Pi project, and I want to make it very easy to use.  My dad will be using it, and I'd like for it to be usable without having to interact with the terminal.  I just want a basic GUI that prompts for values to be input, processes them, and allows my program to act on them.  I want the values to be repeatedly used, but easy to change when the conditions change, there's an error, etc.  I thought the easiest way to do this would be a light weight Ubuntu app, but I may be wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this going to run on the pi or on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edit*: This is a very old post. If you come across now, you should look out for versions of `qt5` instead of `qt4`. Qt5 is [even more awesome](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt5-intro.html).

---

You should go for [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) framework ([What is Qt?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29)) which offers great and well documented GUI libraries which work across multiple platforms.

For Python there is [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) ([What is PyQt?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt)) which offers python bindings for the Qt framework.

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 pyqt4-dev-tools
```

To get started, [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-ubuntu-linux/) is a simple "Hello World"-tutorial:

Create a file `~/tmp/helloworld.py`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QPushButton("Hello World", None)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```

Run it:

```
python ~/tmp/helloworld.py
```

In addition, you can use the [Qt Designer](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Qt_Designer) IDE which is available in the ubuntu repositories and offers some nice development features for GUIs.

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-designer
```

Comment: This looks nice.  Would it be able to be put into an application of sorts?  Or at least an executable file to make it very point-and-clickable?

Comment: Of course you can compile your code and create an executable for various platforms. I'm doing that with `cmake` and `qt-creator`. But that's another question. :)